# How to debug a web page that doesn't work on mobile but works when using chrome remote debugger? iOS shows "Can not decode raw data"

Tags: browser, android, debug, ios

I have a web page that works on desktop chrome and IE, and works correctly in mobile emulation in Chrome.
However, it shows only a blank white page on android, and in iOS shows "Can not decode raw data".

When I plug my android phone into my PC by USB and use chrome remote debugging tools everything works OK on the phone.

Some pages of the site function correctly, some do not. I don't load any extra libraries on the pages that don't work.

Can anyone suggest what is going on, or the next steps I should take to debug this ?

Example page that works : https://www.desangosse.fr

Example page that bugs : https://www.desangosse.fr/produit/familles/anti-rongeurs/

EDIT: The page works after a refresh, but not on first load.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : deactivate gzip compression.

In my website I use Wordpress and W3 Total Cache. Go to "Performance" > "Browser cache" and uncheck "Enable HTTP (gzip) compression".